# CSS Overflow-y not scrolling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to replicate something which looks like a full height webmail system using css with bootstrap.

Unfortunately I'm finding that the overflow-y : scroll property is not preventing the #row-email-body div from growing beyond the height of it's parent once it fills up with content.

This is causing the 'webmail' system to expand beyond the height of the viewport which is not desired.

Could anyone provide an explanation why it is not behaving as I expected or any guidance around the methods I've employed to construct this page?

```css
@CHARSET"UTF-8";
 html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#page, #row-body, #col-left, #col-right, #row-email-body {
    height: 100%
}
#row-email-header {
    height: 140px;
}

#row-email-body {
    overflow: scroll;    
}

#row-header, #row-body, #row-email-header, #row-email-body {
    display: table-row;
}
#page, #col-right {
    display:table;
    padding:0;
}
#row-header {
    height: 130px;
}

/* Debug Colors Only */
#row-header { background: #ddd; }
#row-body { background: #ece; }
#col-left { background: #ccc; }
#col-right { background: #bbb; }
#row-email-header { background: #999; }
#row-email-body { background: #888; }
#page { background: #eee; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="page" class="container">
    <div id="row-header" class="row">HEADER-ROW - Logo</div>
    <div id="row-body" class="row">
        <div id="col-left" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">COL-LEFT - Emails</div>
        <div id="col-right" class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
            <div id="row-email-header" class="row">
                <div class="col col-md-12">EMAIL HEADER - To/From etc.</div>
            </div>
            <div id="row-email-body" class="row">
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see the problem you're describing

Comment: Hi, i've added more content to help highlight the issue. The entire page should not expand beyond the height of the viewport however the lack of the overflow:scroll working correctly is causing it to do so. Also don't forget to view the snippet in full screen.

Comment: Ah I see, the code you provided is working as intended, you just expect a different result. I'll whip up an answer and fiddle for you shortly.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `overflow` will only work when the content tries to exceed the container. In your example, the `#row-email-body` has no set height, and due to the nature of HTML (which is to expand vertically to fit the content), the content was pushing out.

In order to achieve the scroll, your `#row-email-body` has to have a set `height`.

However, since I assume you want this height to be dynamic, and not be something static like '300px', I whipped up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sharf224/62a28pj2/) to demonstrate absolute positioning to create a full-screen version without pushing outside.

The updated CSS:

```
@CHARSET"UTF-8";
 html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#page{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
#row-body {
    position:absolute;
    top:130px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
#col-right{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:33.3333%;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
#col-left{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:33.3333%;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
#row-email-header {
    height: 140px;
}


#row-header, #row-email-header, #row-email-body {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}

#row-header {
    height: 130px;
}

#row-email-body {
 position:absolute;
    top:140px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

/* Debug Colors Only */
#row-header { background: #ddd; }
#row-body { background: #ece; }
#col-left { background: #ccc; }
#col-right { background: #bbb; }
#row-email-header { background: #999; }
#row-email-body { background: #888; }
#page { background: #eee; }
```

and the html:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="row-header">HEADER-ROW - Logo</div>
    <div id="row-body">
        <div id="col-left" >COL-LEFT - Emails</div>
        <div id="col-right" >
            <div id="row-email-header" >
                <div>EMAIL HEADER - To/From etc.</div>
            </div>
            <div id="row-email-body">
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, bootstrap's columns and rows interfere with this, so those had to be removed. This does not give you the same responsiveness you had, where the email list would collapse into whole rows. You will have to use media-queries, or perhaps some of bootstraps classes, to create a responsive/alternate view if desired.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm finding that the `overflow-y : scroll` property is not preventing the #row-email-body div from growing beyond the height of it's parent once it fills up with content.

To have such a behavior you need to set the height of `#row-email-body` and display it as a `block`;

**`overflow-y : scroll`** property specifies whether to clip content, render a scroll bar, or display `overflow content` of a `block-level` element, when it overflows at the top and bottom edges.

here's a snippet of working scrolling

```css
@CHARSET"UTF-8";
 html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    
}
#page, /*#row-body,*/ #col-right #col-left,#row-email-body {
    height: 100%
}
#row-email-header {
    height: 140px;
}

#row-email-body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 150px;
    display: block    
}

#row-header, #row-body, #row-email-header,/* #row-email-body */{
    display: table-row;
}
#page, /*#col-right*/ {
    display:table;
    padding:0;
}
#row-header {
    height: 130px;
}

/* Debug Colors Only */
#row-header { background: #ddd; }
#row-body { background: #ece; }
#col-left { background: #ccc; }
#col-right { background: #bbb; }
#row-email-header { background: #999; }
#row-email-body { background: #888; }
#page { background: #eee; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="page" class="container">
    <div id="row-header" class="row">HEADER-ROW - Logo</div>
    <div id="row-body" class="row">
        <div id="col-left" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">COL-LEFT - Emails</div>
        <div id="col-right" class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
            <div id="row-email-header" class="row">
                <div class="col col-md-12">EMAIL HEADER - To/From etc.</div>
            </div>
            <div id="row-email-body" class="row">
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
                <p>email body</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the **display: table-row** from the **#row-email-body**. Then you can set maximum height for the same div with **max-height:** *height* like this:

```
#row-email-body {
    max-height: 600px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#row-header, #row-body, #row-email-header, { // Removed #row-email-body here!
    display: table-row;
}
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that doesn't allow #row-email-body to fill the rest of the viewport. I'm not feeling that the way I've addressed this challenge is incorrect and may be unachievable using this method. Thank you anyway.